# htaccess: Remove and disable file ending

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd plastered all over the Internet that this code in your .htaccess file will remove the file ending:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

However, although enables the URL without file ending, it does not disable the URL with file ending.

Essentially, what I'd like to force any attempt for an request with file ending (domain.com/sample.php) to end up without file ending (domain.com/sample)

I'm sure someone will have covered this somewhere, but I cannot find anything.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this extra rule before your existing rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: One more question/thought:

Would it now be better to keep links, e.g. in the site navigation, without file ending (href="sample") or would it for some reason be better to have the file endings (href="sample.php")?

Comment: It is always better to have links as `/sample` instead of `/sample.php` Above 301 rules is for old cached link from search engines.