# Remove folder and file ending from URL uing .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make my private website, but I'm having trouble with the `.htaccess` file.

basically, my URL looks like this:
`http://example.com/pages/file.php`

Now I am trying to remove the file ending (`.php` and maybe `.pdf`) and the `/pages/` from the URL
So far I managed to remove the `.php` ending, but am unsure how to do the same with the `.pdf`. Simply copying the code and editing it for `.pdf` did not work. For my PDF I get a 404 error, but I've double-checked that the file is there

I'v been searching the internet for a bit now, and I found some solutions for removing the `/pages/`, but I need to do it, so that the server still finds the file in `root/pages/file.php`, because from the File not found message I get that it just changes the URL. Maybe I can set something up to change the URL after the page is already loaded? Or is there another command th just change the URL displayed, but not the one the server works with?

My research:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601051/htaccess-remove-and-disable-file-ending

> https://jweiland.net/know-how/internet/htaccess-konfigurieren.html#c6256 (German)

> https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/Webserver/htaccess/Umleitungen_mit_mod_rewrite (German)

> https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

This is the `.htaccess` I have now:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.pdf[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.pdf [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Why would you want PDFs without extension as well? Usually that’s done for “pages”, anything that returns HTML documents - but not for binary assets, such as PDFs.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` just checks if what was requested does not match an existing file, and then the following Rule will rewrite that to `$1.php` already. You can not do the same thing for `.pdf` afterwards, because those rules don’t even get evaluated any more now. You either need to _test_ if the requested URI with `.php` or `.pdf` added at the end actually exists; or find a different way to separated between the two to begin with, like separate folders.